# calculate effect size for fixed effect variable with >2 levels binomial glmm (lme4)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, glmm, effect-size

I have a mixed effects model with a binomial outcome which I constructed using glmer from the lme4 package in R. In the output from `summary(model)` I get estimates for each of the fixed effects. This is fine for continuous and dichotomous variables, however, for categorical variables with >2 levels this does not work (as the output produces contrasts). To get the effects for these, I use the `anova` or `drop1` functions. However, these do not include any measure of effect size.

Using the effectsize package, I tried `effectsize(model)` which provides effect sizes and confidence intervals for the output produced by `summary(model)`, however, what I am interested in is the *global* effect of a categorical variable with >2 levels (the equivalent to Cohen's d when conducting a normal ANOVA).

How can I calculate this?

Comment: How would you define such a global effect size?

Comment: the equivalent to cohen's d when conducting a normal ANOVA

Comment: Please add that new information to the post as an edit! not only as a comment. Not everybody reads comments, and we want posts to be self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

There aren't really global effect sizes for glm(m)s.

You can try Nagelkerke's pseudo-$R^2$. E.g.:

```r
m1 <- glm(gear ~ hp, data = mtcars,
          family = poisson())

m2 <- glm(gear ~ hp + am, data = mtcars,
          family = poisson())

performance::r2(m1)
#> # R2 for Generalized Linear Regression
#>   Nagelkerke's R2: 0.017

performance::r2(m2)
#> # R2 for Generalized Linear Regression
#>   Nagelkerke's R2: 0.657
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>